# Upload html website to wordpress server

Tags: html, wordpress

I have a wordpress website. I am a web developer. I want to showcase my websites. So, I want to host them in my server. They are simply php mysql website. No CMS is used. The code is self written. But I can not upload them within wordpress. I have tried uploading them into a subdomain. But that is not working too. While I am putting the address of the sub domain, wordpress is generating a 404 error against the address. Please suggest me something so that I can host the websites side by side of Wordpress. Sorry for my bad English. Thanks in advance.

-Suman

Answer (score 0):

You could host the websites in a folder on your ftp server and then you can link to them or use a [Iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tag_iframe.asp) to view them.

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tag_iframe.asp

---

If you are using php and sql sites, and not the HTML websites you mention in your question title, you will need to run the code and databases in subdomains or similar

Comment: If this has answered your question, please accept it by clicking the tick icon on the left of the page.